# Facebook app requests

Tags: facebook, apprequests

I have a facebook application that is a tab inside a fan page.

I have used the signed request to see if a user likes the page and show content based on that.

I have also managed to use get the facebook user id after prompting the user to log in and grant access to the application.

What I CAN'T do, is get the 'apprequests' functionality to work.  I have tried it a couple of ways:

FYI - am using this version of jquery: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: 'myappid', xfbml: true, cookie: true, oauth: true });
    };

    function inviteFriends() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Enter this cool competition http://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Test-Fan-Page/204123762998981?sk=app_308637695832192',
            redirect_uri: 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Test-Fan-Page/204123762998981?sk=app_308637695832192',
            display: 'iframe'
        },
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
    }
```

....

when I do this, there are 2 issues (and I think they're probably related)
1. The request isn't sent to the selected users
2. The function for the response isn't called.
When I call the FB.ui method, I can selected users, but when I do that, the dialog shows a loading screen and just shuts down.

One thing that I found strange was that when I didn't include the 'redirect_uri' parameter (which from what I can see should not be necessary), I got an error saying the application did not own the call back url.

I have also tried doing it this way

```
    var message = 'Enter this cool competition';
                var requestUrl = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=308637695832192&redirect_uri=http://localhost:51934/Default.aspx&message=' + message;
                window.top.location.href = requestUrl;
```

This also appears to work, I can select users and it appears to work - I get the users that I added in the to[0], to[1], etc query string paramaeters.

Is there anything I'm doing that's wrong and could be causing this?  When I request the user to authorize the app, I'm just requesting standard access, as far as I can tell from the Facebook docs this is all that should be required.  I'm also wandering if there's some limitations on what can be done inside a page ta?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have been wrestling all night with this issue too and think I may have a possible solution for you to try.

For number 1) In the app settings I had only set the urls for the Page Tab option, when I selected to ALSO have the app as a facebook app suddenly the requests were delivered and all showing.

For number 2) I had redirect_uri set and the call back function was not being called, the dialog would just close. I think redirect_uri is only actioned when the display is popup. Try removing the redirect_uri option and the display option

By the way, I was also getting that error regarding not owning the redirect uri. I don't know for sure what I changed that meant I stopped getting it but suspect it was when I moved the sdk init html to just after the body tag as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ I had previously had it just before the close of the body tag. Hope this helps.

Comment: #1 was my problem and this fixed it! Thanks!